# Reset Password is not working in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: php, magento

I have magento 1.9.2.2 installed in my shop. When I click on forget password and enter email address, it send the reset link to my email, once I click on reset link it redirect to other link

Comment: Is this showing you blank page ?

Comment: Did you apply any patch to Magento?

Comment: can you share the urls, I suspect you have installed some webkul extension.

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento 1.9.2.2 it is required to send a form key with the forgot password form.

In your template `customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml` put:

`getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` just under the tag. Refresh the cache and see if the hidden input with a form key is present in the page.

Hopefully this will solve your issue :)